# Accurate model for the height of Tidal Bulge from the Moon using Binomial expansion?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How do you create an equation for the height of the tidal bulge on Earth by the Moon using binomial expansion?

Thank you!

[General form for Binomial Eq with n=-1/2?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhTQz.jpg)

[First six terms?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjG8m.jpg)

Comment: Why is this a mathematics question, rather than an astronomy (or physics or geodetics, etc) question?  You must have read or heard something about the topic: where, and in what context.

Comment: Because I understand the physics. I don't understand where binomial expansion comes in nor have I even done any problems with binomial expansion that I can remember. Prof says I'll understand what he wants when I figure out how many expansions I need to take this out to. I read the physics Stack. I need the math part. I hate algebra. I am actually better at Calc. I've read a lot this weekend. I actually need to teach this one thing at the end of the semester so the more I can understand it, the better. Sorry for the etiquette. I can relist if there's a better way. Thanks

Comment: Well, good luck!  I don't understand the physics at all, but assume something like $F=g/R^2$ in a naive model gets replaced by something like $F=g/(R\pm\epsilon)^2$, reflecting the fact that not all parts of the Earth are equidistant to the Moon (or vice versa).  So a binomial expansion of  $F=(g/R^2)(1\pm \epsilon/R)^{-2}$  might well come in.

Comment: Hey, thanks. that is definitely the start of the model. I will fill this in with my own answers/work as I go. I think this will be a good string. Would you have a look at the binomials? I think I am did not expand this correctly. The reason for "b" is change of base in the earlier physics modeling work that my prof helps with.

Comment: In the "general form" image, I think you have the wrong coefficients for $b^2$ and $b^3$.  I could not read the handwriting on the other image.  I think you should check your work carefully, and not rely on me for its accuracy.  Good luck!

Comment: I agree entirely! Thanks. It was hasty and the last few terms were very dumb arithmetic errors. I just wanted to confirm I was even doing a binomial expansion correctly.